# Using levels and labels - how can I maintain data that isn't included in the levels?

Tags: r, label, levels

I am using levels to label my data, but there is some data that has been incorrectly inputed and does not fit within the levels that I want to label. I'd like that data to remain as is, rather than be considered NA when labels are applied - how can I accomplish this?

Seg_VL$riskcomp4 <- factor(Seg_VL$riskcomp4, levels = c(0,1,2),
label= c("A", "B" , "C"))

So in this example, I have a few observations that are not 0, 1, or 2. I'd like those observations to remain unlabeled rather than having them show up as NA.

Thanks for any help!

Comment: I don't think you will find an easy fix for this. You could always write a function that checks which input values are not in the accepted set, and then extends the accepted set, the levels, and the labels with these extra values and creatse a factor from them

Comment: Thanks for the response! I think I may just concede to them showing up as NA.